# Why is this relation between norms true?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Why is this statement true?

For any sequence

$$f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{K}, ||f||_\infty \leq ||f||_2 \leq ||f||_1$$

I assume the norms look like this:

$$||f||_\infty = sup_x |f(x)|$$

$$||f||_2 = \int |f(x)|^2 dx$$

$$||f||_1 = \int |f(x)| dx$$

Comment: You're missing the square root in the norm $2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When talking about $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$, the norm is: $$\|f(n)\|^p_p=\sum_{n=1}^\infty|f(n)|^p=\int_\mathbb{N}|f|^pd\mu$$ when treating $\ell^p$ as $L^p(\mathbb{N},\mu)$ with $\mu$ being the counting measure, namely $\mu(A)=|A|$ where $A\subset \mathbb{N}$. Looking at the norms this way, it is obvious why $\|f\|_\infty\leq \|f\|_2, \|f\|_\infty \leq\|f\|_1$, since: $$\|f\|_\infty=\max_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|f(n)|\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty|f(n)|=\|f\|_1$$ And: $$\|f\|^2_\infty=(\max_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|f(n)|)^2\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty|f(n)|^2=\|f\|^2_2$$

As for the second inequality, it is trivial if $f=0$. Now we assume $f\neq 0$, and define $g=\frac{f}{\|f\|_1}$. So $\|g\|_1=1$ and $|g(n)|\leq 1$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |g(n)|^2\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|g(n)|=1\Rightarrow \|g\|_2\leq1$$ Finally: $$\|f\|_2=\|f\|_1\|g\|_2\leq\|f\|_1$$
as desired.

Comment: Do you know why $l_1 \subseteq l_2 \subseteq l_\infty$ ?